# The term "operations" in IT - singular or plural?

Tags: grammar

The term "operations" in IT is referred to all tasks for running and maintaining systems.
It is often abbreviated to "ops". In this form it is used in a lot of IT-related terms like "DevOps", "GitOps", "FinOps", etc.

The word "operations" looks like a plural to me. Still, using the abbreviated form like a plural feels wrong. For example - which one is correct?

- "GitOps make it easy to..."
- "GitOps make**s** it easy to...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operations is the collective of all tasks. The word in itself is called "operations" and not "operation". Also, one does not call it "operation" when referring to a single task within the "operations".

Therefore the correct answer is: "GitOps makes it easy to..."

For reference:
"GitOps offers developers a way to manage operational workflows, particularly for Kubernetes, that relies on familiar processes, e.g., pull requests, which they already use to merge code."

**Notice:** "GitOps offers"

Comment: I have a somewhat different perspective. "DevOps" to me is plural. It is "Development Operations." In a sentence, I would write "Development Operations include nightly builds, release distribution, compiler directives..." However, in many sentences something missing is implied. The DevOps team, for example. In which case, you might write "DevOps does the nightly builds" because you are referring to the DevOps team or department.

Comment: ["DevOps is" the combination of cultural philosophies, practices, and tools that increases an organisation’s ability to deliver applications and services at high velocity: evolving and improving products at a faster pace than organisations using traditional software development and infrastructure management processes.] Taken from AWS.

Comment: The focus here is that the operations you are taking about does not exist. You do not call individual segments of DevOps as operations. And DevOps as a whole is a single term for the team/task and hence it is considered as a singular entity. Within that, these functions or tasks are individual and come under devops in a taxonomical sense.

Comment: It's not just an opinion that the word "operations" is plural. It is plural. It may be perfectly acceptable jargon in the IT field to consider DevOps a "a single term for the team/task", but that doesn't change the grammar. I would recommend that whether it is being referred to in singular or plural terms matters:  "DevOps" is an important department" but also "Development operations are essential components of the software engineering effort." Your style guide may vary.

Comment: Operations is a singular term. The collective task of multiple single tasks are known as "operations". It's like aerobics or acoustics.

Comment: Which operations are performed by DevOps? The "are" is absolutely necessary in that sentence; 'operations' refers to more than one operation. Claiming "Operations" is only singular ignores cases in which it is not. Yes, there are collective nouns that take singular verbs, like "flock." 
For context, from Wikipedia: "Different forms of English handle verb agreement with collective count nouns differently. For example, users of British English generally accept that collective nouns take either singular or plural verb forms depending on context and the metonymic shift that it implies."